# Генеалогическое дерево исключений и мой пример

Tags: java

Прочитал из книги:

Если вы пишете несколько блоков catch, вам следует располагать их в порядке, согласно тому, как соответствующие исключения унаследованы друг от друга. Например, так как EOFException - это подкласс IOException, нужно расположить блок catch для подкласса вначале. Если же первым поместить catch для IOException, тогда программа никогда не достигнет FileNotFoind или EOFException, Так как первый catch будет их перехватывать.

Не очень понял вот это:

> Если же первым поместить catch для IOException, тогда программа
>   никогда не достигнет FileNotFoind или EOFException, Так как первый
>   catch будет их перехватывать.

Второй вопрос: Зачем нам в этой "структуре" FileNotFoundException и EOFException если они наследуются от IOException и он может сделать всё за них? Или как-то работает всё по-другому?

Расскажите по подробнее, если можно с примерами. Заранее спасибо!

```
public void getScores(){
            try{
                fileScores.read();
                System.out.println("Счёт игры успешно загружен");
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Не найден файл Scores");
            }catch (EOFException e1){
                System.out.println("Достигнут конец файла");
            }catch (IOException e2){
                System.out.println("Проблема при чтении файла " + e2.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Есть разные методы реализации. И правда, можно таким способом делать ветвления, можно вообще сделать один Exception, и каждый вид исключения проверять  является ли `exception is EOFException` - но тогда получим более громоздкую запись с кучей if-ов. Если есть "словарь" на исключения то тогда соглашуть что можно всё обьеденить условно `println(except_dictionary[ typename(exception)])`

Comment: А зачем делать ветвления именно как в примере? И почему если бы IOException был бы в первом sout(е) , то почему программа никогда не достигнет FileNotFoundException и EOFException если они от него наследуются

Comment: Потому что механизм сложнее чем вы думаете. Сначало проверяется совпадение по 0-му уровню (главному). Если главный "тип исключения" не найден, то только потом идет поиск по "деткам первого уровня". Если 1-го уровня нету то по 2-му и т д. EOFException сначала будет обработан именно EOFException, а только если обработчика EOFException нету - то перейдёт на IOException. эта конструкция работает примерно как `switch + case` обвёрнутые в цикл. Если совпадений не найдено - то цикл берёт следующий уровень. Откройте раздел **исключения в java**, внимательно изучите. Я тоже самое пишу что там.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Я не могу судить сделал ли автор ошибку FileNotFoundException , потому что java (в отличие от других сред) проверяет, какие исключения генерирует класс (или метод...), и если вы не все виды исключений  охватили - не даёт собрать код. И я плохо знаю java. Поэтому тут два варианта 1) java не даст собрать без FileNotFoundException  2) автор книги ошибся, возможно ранее там  в коде было ещё и открытие файла.